# Had been a great journey or was a great journey

Tags: grammar

what is the difference between these two sentences ?

- It had been a great journey.
- It was a great journey.

Answer (score 2):

It was a great journey : Simple Past. We use simple past for a completed action in the past. Example: 
I  saw  a movie  yesterday.

It had been a great journey: Past Perfect. We use Past Perfect for a completed action before something in the past. Example:
I  had  never  seen  such  a  beautiful  beach  before  I  went  to  Kauai.